# Create scheduled job(IOCL_INVOICE_DATA_S_JOB) to call the procedure (IOCL_INVOICE_DATA_S_PROC)every hour

Tags: oracle, scheduler

Create scheduled job (IOCL_INVOICE_DATA_S_JOB) to call the procedure (IOCL_INVOICE_DATA_S_PROC) every hour

Need correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's `dbms_scheduler`'s job.

For example, job that runs every hour from Monday till Friday (i.e. doesn't run on weekend):

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      job_name         => 'iocl_invoice_data_s_job',
      job_type         => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      job_action       => 'BEGIN iocl_invoice_data_s_proc; end;',
      start_date       =>
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('15.05.2023 11:00 Europe/Zagreb', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi TZR'),
      repeat_interval  =>
         'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYHOUR=1; BYMINUTE=0',
      enabled          => TRUE,
      comments         => 'Put some comment here, if you want');
END;
/
```

Modify everything you don't like. If you aren't sure what parameters represent, check Oracle documentation.